# Cookies on Android/Iphone vs Desktop

Tags: asp.net, iphone, android, cookies

I am in the process of building an mobile/web application. I want to use cookies for persistence, but I am wondering of the cookies in firefox workings the sames as say the mobile browsers and will it be recognized. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies work the same in every browser out there that supports cookies. Which is basically every browser since 1995.